# Board games Online

Tags: online

The questions and answers I found are pretty old, hence, here I am:

I played a few games on Tabletop simulator on steam. I found it rather rubbish and not working very well, especially with a not-so-fast connection. On the other hand, I played Dominion on [dominion.games](http://dominion.games), and the experience has been quite positive. Is there any other platform where games can be played in similar manner? (no download, played on browser and possibly lightweight).

I don't mind downloading a game if the playing experience is good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm playing on [Board game arena (BGA)](https://boardgamearena.com/) and I find it excellent for several reasons (IMHO):

- Great catalogue of games, esp. for euro + family games.
- Free to play along in all games
- Cheap premium membership where you can start all games yourself
- Functional, relatively lightweight interface - works a treat on PC and on tablets/phones
- Very active in these times (2020)
- Sign up with Google(...) account, so barrier of entry is low.

A possible Con might be that it's not as pretty as the real thing. Nor as pretty as some dedicated app could be.

But, *seriously*, just google "board games online" and invest an hour to find the platform you like.

Answer (score 1):

Yucata is a good one. It's designed for turn based games rather than live games and ones where everyone takes their turn simultaneously. It's almost exclusively card games.

You can play multiple games at once; if you're on turn in a number of different games, you can easily click through each of them and make your turns.

Games can take a number of days to finish. I tend to log on every few hours and make all my turns; if my opponent is also logged on we might get a few turns in each, otherwise just the one until a few hours later. Providing you're ok with playing like that, it works great (e.g. as a distraction from work...)

It is possible to play live games (either with friends, or with strangers by requesting a live opponent), but there is no way to ensure your opponent plays live i.e. there are no time limits for turns.

I didn't know most of the games on there, but it's been nice to learn some new ones.

Finally, there's a cool level/points based system; if you're the kind of person who likes getting Stack Exchange badges, you'll enjoy this feature.

I also back BGA too, as the other comment recommends.